# Is Angular 5.2.3 a stable version?

Tags: angular, angular5

I am creating an app with Angular 5.2.3 and Laravel 5.4. 
I want to know whether the angular version is stable or not, so that I can continue. I am getting mixed answers from my search. Help me out please.

> Angular CLI: 1.6.7
>   Node: 8.9.4
>   OS: win32 x64
>   Angular: 5.2.3

Comment: No issue with downgrading this question. I really dont want to downgrade the angular version. After giving me a proper answer , people can downgrade this question.

Comment: How do you define "stable"? It's a major version no longer in beta, it was released. Is that stable? Or do you need a LTS guarantee?

Comment: Stable means not beta. Am using angular 5.2.3 and if it is beta, then no point of building a big application with that. As I am new to angular 5 obviously I have this doubt because Angular is going to release version 6 next month.

Comment: I don't really understand how you can think Angular 5 is in Beta... did you check their front page? If you get mixed answers to that question, you need to work on your research skills. Anyway, you got a good answer.

Comment: Anyways, I dont have much info about angular for argument. SInce I got the answer i need am happy. And am accepting its matter of my research skill lacking. At the same time I dont mind clearing my doubts in any way of communication as am still in my early stage of career. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Angular team said in [their documentation](https://angular.io/docs), the stable version is 5.2.5, so yes, Angular 5 is stable.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply and happy to see this. So i dont need to downgrade my angular version.

Comment: No problem!! Anyway always check in the documentation the last stable version!! Is the easiest and fast way to check if the version is stable or not ;)

Comment: Yeah. Thanks anyways !